# Swit - I want to get the value stored in the keychain

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

I want to get the values ​​(group, ID, password) stored in the keychain.

I can get only the password. I want to get group and ID.

Get method is `getKeyChain`

```
import Foundation

// キーチェーンの保存・取得を管理する
extension ViewController {

    // 保存
    func saveKeyChain() {

        // group
        let grp = "AA"

        // ID
        let id = "0001"

        // password
        let str = "test"
        let data = str.data(using: .utf8)



        guard let _data = data else {
            return
        }

        // APIを実行する際の引数設定
        // これをSecItemCopyMatching の第一引数に渡すと結果を受け取ることができる
        let dic: [String: Any] = [kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword, // パスワードクラス
            kSecAttrGeneric as String: grp,                // 自由項目（グループとする）
            kSecAttrAccount as String: id,                 // アカウント（ログインID）
            kSecValueData as String: _data,                // パスワード本体
            kSecAttrService as String: "test"]            // サービス名

        print(dic)

        var itemAddStatus: OSStatus?
        // 保存データが存在するかの確認
        let matchingStatus = SecItemCopyMatching(dic as CFDictionary, nil)
        if matchingStatus == errSecItemNotFound {
            // 保存
            itemAddStatus = SecItemAdd(dic as CFDictionary, nil)
        } else if matchingStatus == errSecSuccess {
            // 更新
            itemAddStatus = SecItemUpdate(dic as CFDictionary,[kSecAttrGeneric as String: _data] as CFDictionary)
            itemAddStatus = SecItemUpdate(dic as CFDictionary,[kSecAttrAccount as String: _data] as CFDictionary)
            itemAddStatus = SecItemUpdate(dic as CFDictionary,[kSecValueData as String: _data] as CFDictionary)
        } else {
            print("保存失敗")
        }
        // 保存・更新ステータス確認
        if itemAddStatus == errSecSuccess {
            print("正常終了")
        } else {
            print("保存失敗")
        }
    }

    // 取得
    func getKeyChain(key: String) -> String? {

        let dic: [String: Any] = [kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword,
                                  kSecAttrService as String: key,
                                  kSecReturnData as String: kCFBooleanTrue as Any,
                                  kSecMatchLimit as String  : kSecMatchLimitOne]as [String : Any]

        var data: AnyObject?

        // ポインタ：変数のメモリ上の位置（番地）を格納している
        // 変数をポインタに変換してポインタ経由でアクセスする
        let matchingStatus = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &data){
            SecItemCopyMatching(dic as CFDictionary, UnsafeMutablePointer($0))
        }


        if matchingStatus == errSecSuccess {
            print("取得成功")
            if let getData = data as? Data,
                let getStr = String(data: getData, encoding: .utf8) {
                return getStr
            }
            print("取得失敗: Dataが不正")
            return nil
        } else {
            print("取得失敗")
            return nil
        }
    }

    // 削除
    func deleteKeyChain() {
        // 削除するqueryを設定
        let dic: [String: Any] = [kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword,
                                  kSecAttrService as String: "test"]            // サービス名

        if SecItemDelete(dic as CFDictionary) == errSecSuccess {
            print("削除成功")
        } else {
            print("削除失敗")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your updated method does not make sense, your `get` method doesn't have `account`.

Comment: how to get account?

Comment: That's the `id` you are using in your `save` method. Your `save` and `get` method must use the same requests. The same service and the same account.

Comment: Is it impossible to get ”kSecAttrService” as a key?

Comment: I want to get all key...